# In MySql, how can I use the 'REPLACE' function when defining a stored procedure? The query cannot be executed due to quotes

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to run the below stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RNS_CLEANTEXT_MAX_LENGTH()
BEGIN
 SELECT MAX(LENGTH(rns_cleantext) - LENGTH(REPLACE(rns_cleantext," ", ""))+1) FROM rns;
END
```

However this query doesn't run as I get the message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

I've also attempted single quotes, escaped quotes and as above double quotes.

Any idea.

Fixed by @eggyal:

The fixed query now looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RNS_CLEANTEXT_MAX_LENGTH()
 SELECT MAX(LENGTH(rns_cleantext) - LENGTH(REPLACE(rns_cleantext," ", ""))+1) FROM fns;
```

As @eggyal points out the Begin and End statements are not required. And in the cases where they are I have to modify the delimiter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> Each stored program contains a body that consists of an SQL statement. This statement may be a compound statement made up of several statements separated by semicolon (`;`) characters. For example, the following stored procedure has a body made up of a [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) block that contains a [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-statement.html) statement and a [`REPEAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/repeat.html) loop that itself contains another [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set-statement.html) statement:
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
> BEGIN
>   SET @x = 0;
>   REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
> END;
> ```
>
> If you use the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) delimiter, use the `delimiter` command. The following example shows how to do this for the `dorepeat()` procedure just shown. The delimiter is changed to `//` to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to `;` before invoking the procedure. This enables the `;` delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) itself.
>
> ```
> mysql> delimiter //
>
> mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
>     -> BEGIN
>     ->   SET @x = 0;
>     ->   REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
>     -> END
>     -> //
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
>
> mysql> delimiter ;
>
> mysql> CALL dorepeat(1000);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT @x;
> +------+
> | @x   |
> +------+
> | 1001 |
> +------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> You can redefine the delimiter to a string other than `//`, and the delimiter can consist of a single character or multiple characters. You should avoid the use of the backslash (“`\`”) character because that is the escape character for MySQL.
>
> The following is an example of a function that takes a parameter, performs an operation using an SQL function, and returns the result. In this case, it is unnecessary to use `delimiter` because the function definition contains no internal `;` statement delimiters:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE FUNCTION hello (s CHAR(20))
> mysql> RETURNS CHAR(50) DETERMINISTIC
>     -> RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT hello('world');
> +----------------+
> | hello('world') |
> +----------------+
> | Hello, world!  |
> +----------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

In your case, since your sproc comprises only a single statement, you can simply remove the [`BEGIN ... END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html) block.

Comment: Aha! All I had to do was remove the first semi-colon at the end of the select statement, and add one at the end of the stored procedure. The problem was the semi-colons, not the apostrophes.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama: I never mentioned apostrophes.

Comment: Yep. I'm managing to get confused between meetings. Will update in a second. Thanks though.